# Gradle dependencies not added as libraries in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, gradle

I created an intellij Gradle project for some groovy code. Gradle correctly resolved the dependencies and has them added in the `Project Structure`'s modules tab, however they are not loaded in the `Libraries` tab... Because of this it is impossible to compile the project, it gives me errors on missing libraries. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on this, having only just discovered *a* solution to this problem myself, but I found that using the `idea` Gradle plugin resolved the same issue for me.

So, in `build.gradle` add:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

Then run:

```
gradle idea
```

and Gradle will create the `.iml` files for your project, which Intellij will understand and use to import the libraries. I'd recommend creating a backup of your project first, because if there are other things in your `.iml` files that Intellij needs, I suspect everything will break! I find them a bit of a mystery, personally.

Comment: The `idea` plugin is already applied but I don't see any `idea` task to run... However you are right the problem seems to come from the `.iml` file's configuration. In one of my projects which works correctly, the `.iml` describes the dependencies as libraries like so: `<orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Gradle: javax:javaee-api:6.0" level="project" />` whereas in the other project they are described with a different `type="module-library"` and instead of a `level` attribute they have a `<CLASSES>` tag and inside there is a `<root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/path/.."` />.

Comment: Are you just looking for the task in Intellij? I'm not sure why, but it doesn't show up in the IDE for me either, but definitely does run from the command line. If you just run `gradle idea`, you should find it works. An alternative option that might work is just re-importing the project into Intellij, but that's probably not ideal because you might lose some settings, like run configurations (I think)

Comment: I don't have gradle installed I only use it inside intellij so I don't have access to its cli. Regardless, changing the `.iml` file manually doesn't seem to have fixed this so it might not be that at all. I'll do some more tests, maybe install gradle to try your solution out. Although I'm pretty sure IntelliJ's gradle has run and configured the project like it is supposed to. However since this is an outside project it is possible that the `build.gradle` file has some options that mess things up...